# Explanation of phase changing/solid and liquid water existing in the same container at same temp

Tags: phase, temperature, liquids

I was trying to explain to a friend the other day why when ice and water are in the same container, the water is 32 degrees Fahrenheit or 0 celcius, but not frozen, because the ambient temp is above freezing and the ice I'd going through a phase change. Can anybody explain or label this please?